# React - preselect checkbox with same option selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown selection that renders a few options, when one of the options are selected the same `name` that's selected should also be checked in the checkbox section.

I have mocked up a quick reproduction in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jjy5n7l94w).

I was thinking something along the lines of holding a selected value on the data object:

```
this.state = {
  //other state values
  selectedName: true
};
```

Then map the checkbox values on it -- I'm unsure of this part. And somehow the state inside `updateSelectorField` needs to be updated with the selected value.

```
updateSelectorField = e => {
    this.setState({ selectorField: e.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to select multiple checkboxes on each dropdown select, or just the one that is currently selected in the dropdown?

Comment: Only one option can be selected from the `selectorField` dropdown. So whatever single value is there should be what checkbox is also populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you just need to change the `value` prop on your `CheckboxGroup` component from `this.state.fieldNames` to `this.state.selectorField`.

Like so:

```
<CheckboxGroup
  checkboxDepth={5}
  name="fieldNames"
  value={this.state.selectorField}
  onChange={this.fieldNamesChanged}
  required
>
```

Then also change the state mutation on `fieldNamesChanged` so that `selectorField` is updated with the new value of `newFieldNames`.

Finally, change your method to:

```
updateSelectorField = ({target}) => {
  if (!this.state.selectorField.includes(target.value)) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({selectorField: [...prevState.selectorField, target.value]}));
  }
};
```

I would also remove the `value` attribute from your select, since you don't want it to reflect the changes you do to the checkboxes, but to remain at whatever the user selected.

Comment: Oh my I'm sorry, completely misread your comment above. You should still be able to select other checkboxes as well.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure how this is meant to work (it is an odd behavior), but try the updated answer above.

Comment: So the same values will always be rendered to the dropdown and checkbox group. Let's say I select `caller #` from the dropdown list. The `caller #` checkbox should be `checked` as a result. but other checkboxes can also be selected. If I change the value prop on `CheckboxGroup` to `this.state.selectorField` this won't allow other boxes to selected in addition.

Comment: Updated it again. Try again?

Comment: I updated my sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/jjy5n7l94w. It is not checking the checkbox value that's selected by the `Selector Field:` dropdown

Comment: Just add the initial state for `selectorField` to be `[]` and it will work.

Comment: Ah yeah, I removed that on accident when trying to condense down the demo. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: I actually do have a slight issue, `onChange` of the field names, so for each checkbox that is selected a `<div>` containing some more dropdown/input boxes should be appearing.